# JavaScript/jQuery and "top-level" functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I peruse a jQuery-driven JavaScript source file, I see functions defined like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});

$(function {
    ...
});
```

I *think* I understand the first one: I assume its a function to fire once the entire page is downloaded, yes? If not please correct me!

What really confuses me is the second one. Is this an anonymous function? How/where does it get called? When does it get called (page load)?

I guess I'm used to seeing JavaScript function written the *old* way:

```
function myFunction() {
    ...
}
```

Then I just call `myFunction` anytime I need it. How does this "old" way compare to jQuery's constructs? Thanks for helping me understand any of this confusion!

Comment: You should read the [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3).

Comment: Both are functionally the same. The second is a shorthand version of the first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second function is just a short-hand method for the first method. Both register a callback for the document's "ready" event.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> $(document).ready(handler)
>   $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
>   $(handler)

**EDIT:**
The `ready` event actually fires when the DOM can be safely updated. The event will be raised before external resources like images are fully loaded, but most browsers appear to wait for extenal CSS to finish loading before calling it since scripts often depend on the layout calculations to be complete. The shorthand method jQuery method is very common since it provides an easy to remember and direct method for scripts to change the DOM when it's, well, "ready" for the script.

Comment: Thanks @jimp (+1) - So if I write custom functions that have nothing to do with jQuery, is it standard to still use the "old" way (non-`$(function...`)?

Comment: functions in jquery have everything to do with jquery :)

Comment: The old way to define functions is still valid, but it isn't recommended often because it pollutes the global namespace. It is recommended to wrap global functions within a single object definition (thereby only using one entry in the global namespace), define them within an anonymous function, or define them locally with the var keyword. But you are free to use them, still perfectly valid.

Comment: @jimp - thanks (+1) and you have identified exactly what I suspected and have been confused over. One followup question for you: could you please provide an example of what you mean here? I guess my "mental block" with these anonymous functions is that I don't understand how they could ever be called. How can you call a name-less function? Thanks again (+1)!

Comment: You call it either immediately or through storing it in a variable. `var func = function(msg) { alert(msg); }; func('hello');` or even `(function(data) { /* do something */ })(mydata);`. MDN has [some good info on functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Functions) for more reading.